# Need to identify if two log files have a different timestamp

Tags: file, batch-file, logging, timestamp

I'm looking to check the timestamps of two log files (windows OS) and if they are different I'd like to send an email out to our support email. Any advice would be helpful. I have fair knowledge of batch commands but not an expert.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "file1=c:\somewhere\file1.log"
    set "file2=c:\otherplace\file2.log"

    set "sameFileCount=0"
    for /f %%a in ('
        xcopy /d /l /y "%file1%" "%file2%" ^& xcopy /d /l /y "%file2%" "%file1%"
    ') do if "%%a"=="0" set /a "sameFileCount+=1"

    if not %sameFileCount%==2 (
        echo Files have different timestamps
        rem Your mail command here
    )
```

This will execute two xcopy commands to copy file1 over file2 and file2 over file1, but

- The `/l` switch will make the commands "simulate" the operations, getting only the listing of files that will be copied, but without copying anything.
- The `/d` switch indicates that the "copy" operations should only be done if the filestamps are different.

If none of the two commands indicates that a file must be copied (they indicate 0 files to copy), files have the same timestamp.